# What are equivalents for values "selectNextQuickFix" and "selectPrevQuickFix" in VSCode 1.37.1?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, supertab

I am trying to get the same behaviour in VSCode as in Vim for cycling through the completion list.

With Vim `shift+tab` and `tab` respectively cycle up and down the completion list. I like it because I don't have to move my hand to arrow keys.

I found configuration for that kind of behaviour on [this blog](https://blog.lanzani.nl/2016/tab-in-vscode/).

Problem is that suggested values `selectNextQuickFix` and `selectPrevQuickFix` apparently don't exist anymore in version 1.37.1.

I get this message: `Value is not accepted. Valid values: [bla, bla, list of values]`

Does anyone know which value should I put instead of those two to have the exact same behaviour?

Comment: Those quick fix commands are for.. well, quick fixes, not the completion list. The `suggestion` commands from the blog post you linked still seem to work.

Comment: Yes, I commented out quick fixes and suggestions work of course. I would still like to include quick fixes also...

Comment: Looking through VSCode sources, it looks like code actions don't have their own widget anymore but now use the context menu. Not sure if there's any commands for the up / down navigation there...

Comment: tempted to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68685670/11107541

Answer (score 0):

version: 1.81.1

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "selectNextCodeAction",
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "selectPrevCodeAction",
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
```