# How to move up and down in quick fix suggestions in visual studio code without using arrow keys?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever there is some missing or needs correction in code, visual studio code shows a yellow bulb to show some quick fixes suggestions.

[image]

Is there any way or shortcut by which we can navigate up and down suggestion options shown as in screenshot above without using the arrow keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vscode v1.71 there are three new commands you can use for navigating in the QuickFix menu to go to previous or next source code actions.

```
selectNextCodeAction  // to focus the nextcode action
selectPrevCodeAction  // to focus the previous code action
acceptSelectedCodeAction  // to run the focused/selected code action
```

---

You can see the default keybindings below that have been removed. Note the `-` before the command name in two of the keybindings, that removes those keybindings.

You can make these keybindings (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+u",              // whatever you want here
    "command": "selectPrevCodeAction",  // for v1.71
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "up",                 // default removed
    "command": "-selectPrevCodeAction",  // for v1.71
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+d",          // whatever you want here
    "command": "selectNextCodeAction",   // for v1.71
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "down",             // default removed
    "command": "-selectNextCodeAction",   // for v1.71
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
  }
```

The recent response by loann reminded me of [Visual Studio Code Keybinding for navigation in Quick Fix contextual menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750283/836330) in which I mentioned the curious history of this context key, which went from `CodeActionMenuVisible` to `actionWidgetVisible` to `codeActionMenuVisible`.

---

There is also an extension presented as a fix:
[Keyboard QuickFix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix), but it shouldn't be necessary anymore.

Comment: Hi @Mark, this extension really solved my problem. And suggestions shown by this extension are accurate as shown by the vscode intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Keyboard shortcuts" and search for `selectNextSuggestion`. 
You can rebind this command to any shortcut you like. 
Same goes for `selectPrevSuggestion`. 
I use `cmd + j` for up and cmd `cmd + k` for down ^^

Comment: Did you try this on the QuickFix suggestions?  It does not work.  Wrong kind of suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Dany, I am asking to move up and down in options that come for quick fix suggestions. But here you are suggesting options that come from vscode snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Commands in `"when"` section changed to camelCase, this is updated version I use in `keybindigns.json`

```json
// Quick Fix moving
{
    "key": "alt+i",
    "command": "selectPrevCodeAction",
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
},
{
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "selectNextCodeAction",
    "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
}
```