# VSCode - How to cycle through the tems from the quick fix popup with custom keybindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to cycle through this menu with keyboard but not using Up/Down arrow keys. But I can't find any information on the internet.

[image]

Comment: couldn't you move with keyboard `up/down` buttons?!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686750/836330 same question.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, an acceptable solution would be replace the native quick fix menu with [keyboard-quickfix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalsenn.keyboard-quickfix) extension, and set keybindings for the extension.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.