# Visual Studio Code Keybinding for navigation in Quick Fix contextual menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

After vsCode v1.74 update, I'm having trouble defining custom shortcuts for the Quick Fix contextual menu.

Quickfix Menu

[image: Custom Keys Menu]

Before, I was able to solve it by following this thread https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/55111

Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

This is what I used for months with no problem.

```
 {
        "key": "shift+j",
        "when": "codeActionMenuVisible",
        "command": "selectPrevCodeAction"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+k",
        "when": "codeActionMenuVisible",
        "command": "selectNextCodeAction"
    },
```

To be able to use custom shortcuts for the Quick Fix contextual Menu

Comment: then find out if the commandID is still valid, sometimes they change the name, check if the context variable still exists or has the a different name

Comment: I can't find the context clause `codeActionMenuVisible`  in the list of context clauses anymore.  And no other context clause that seems related - and I looked at them all in the Developer Tools console.  And there is no issue filed on this (yet).  I think you might have to file an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you filed the github issue [selectNextCodeAction custom keybinding not working](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168591) and [revert to old context key ID for code action widget](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/168622/commits/9bc23152c2e9b14ed9c3fc2b0eee55cd1edca906) , but it has been resolved by reverting to the previous context key `codeActionMenuVisible` from the new `actionWidgetVisible` - which I assume was introduced because there are now code actions/quick fixes in the terminal (but should have at least been called out in the Release Notes).

The fix is due to be released as part of the Recovery Build v.1.74.1 which may be out soon.

[As a side note, this key started life as `CodeActionMenuVisible` (note the capitalization) before being switched to the typical camel case version later.]

Comment: No, i didn't.. But thanks so much for your response. Just changed the context key to 'actionWidgetVisible' and it's back to normal.

Comment: But I think they are going back to `codeActionMenuVisible` soon so `actionWidgetVisible` may stop working.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow and just upvoted your answer. there you go!  Thanks again :)